# JOI validate if array has only single matching item. Not more than one

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, joi

**example arrays**:

```javascript
const first = {
    class: 'XYZ',
    people: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        isCreator: false
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Alex",
        isCreator: true
    }]
};
```

```javascript
const second = {
    class: 'XYZ',
    people: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        isCreator: false
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Alex",
        isCreator: false
    }]
};
```

```javascript
const third = {
    class: 'XYZ',
    people: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        isCreator: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Alex",
        isCreator: true
    }]
};
```

I want to validate that **there must be a creator** (`isCreator: true`) in `people` array, but **only one, not more**

My schema looks like this:

```javascript
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    class: Joi.string().required(),
    people: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            id: Joi.number().integer().positive().required(),
            name: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
            isCreator: Joi.boolean().required()
        })
    ).min(2)
    .has(Joi.object().keys({
        id: Joi.number(),
        name: Joi.string(),
        isCreator: Joi.valid(true)  // <-- this
    })).required()
});
```

```javascript
schema.validate(first);
schema.validate(second);
schema.validate(third);
```

- **"first"** array is returning success which is ok as there's only one creator
- **"second"** array is returning failure which is ok as there's not a single creator

But

- **"third"** array is returning success which is wrong as there're 2 matching items i.e. 2 creators. And **this** is my issue actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer with the help of [soltex's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74930870/7109362). Have to make some amendments:

```javascript
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    class: Joi.string().required(),
    people: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            id: Joi.number().integer().positive().required(),
            name: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
            isCreator: Joi.boolean().required()
        })
    )
    // re-added this part
    .has(Joi.object().keys({
        id: Joi.number(),
        name: Joi.string(),
        isCreator: Joi.valid(true)
    }))
    .unique((a, b) =>
        a.isCreator !== false /* also added this --> */ && b.isCreator == a.isCreator
    )
});
```

Now all possible test cases are working absolutely as required. Thanks for the help @soltex

```json
people: [{..., isCreator: false}, {..., isCreator: false}, {..., isCreator: false}]
// is returning error "people" does not contain at least one required match 

people: [{..., isCreator: true}, {..., isCreator: false}, {..., isCreator: true}]
// is returning error "people[2]" contains a duplicate value 

people: [{..., isCreator: true}, {..., isCreator: false}, {..., isCreator: false}]
people: [{..., isCreator: false}, {..., isCreator: true}, {..., isCreator: false}]
// are passing successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unique](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#arrayuniquecomparator-options) and compare your `isCreator` field:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    class: Joi.string().required(),
    people: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            id: Joi.number().integer().positive().required(),
            name: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
            isCreator: Joi.boolean()
        })
    ).unique((a, b) => a.isCreator !== false)
})
```

This way, you can only have one object with `isCreator=true`.

If you send this object:

```
{
    class: 'XYZ',
    people: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        isCreator: false
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Alex",
        isCreator: true
    },{
        id: 3,
        name: "Math",
        isCreator: true
    }]
}
```

You will get the following error:

```
Validation Error: "people[2]" contains a duplicate value
```

Comment: thanks. it is giving mentioned error, but failing other cases like all false `[false, false, false]` should be invalid but schema is passing it, `[true, false, false]`, `[false, true, false]` should be allowed but schema failing it!